# firefox addon to select scripts to load on page

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

i am searching for a Firefox addon to let me choose which scripts load on a page, so if i enable it for some page i can select which js, css to load and enable and disable some resource on view.

i need such addon for web developement and some times to use others scripts, could you please guide me if you know such tool?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try NoScript, sounds like just what you want.

Comment: no it isn't what i want. it blocks or permit all scripts while i want some thing to enable for a page so enable and disble scripts and select which one to load! i thing it should be some thing related to firebug

Comment: I think it should be **Greasemonkey** addon for Firefox > https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/